# Hide several tds inside the table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to hide tds cells inside the first tr. I placed them inside an div with id="status2". I am trying to hide them by calling the following jQuery('#status2').hide(); but they are  not being hidden

Is it possible somehow to hide and to show the 3 tds inside the div on some condition? I do not want in this case to add several ids to the 3 tds.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
 <table border='0' width='100%'>
        <tr >
            <td width="20%"  class="bold">Status 1:</td>
            <td><select name="status1" id="status1"><option value="null">select:</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <!--I want to hide the next 3 tds on some condition-->
            <div id="status2">
            <td colspan="2">&#160;</td>
            <td class="bold">status 2:</td>
            <td><select>
                    <option value="null">select</option>
                    <option value="SV">V - 1</option>
                    <option value="SK">V - 2</option>
            </select></td>
            </div>          
        </tr>
        <tr id="status3">
            <td width="20%" class="bold">Status 3:</td>
            <td><select>
                    <option value="null">select</option>
                    <option value="SV">V - 3</option>
                    <option value="SK">V - 4</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
jQuery('#status2').hide();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of wrapping the TDs in a div, just give each td the same class.

Also, you can't actually run javascript in the script tag that is remotely loading a file.

```js
jQuery('.status2').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <table border='0' width='100%'>
        <tr >
            <td width="20%"  class="bold">Status 1:</td>
            <td><select name="status1" id="status1"><option value="null">select:</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <!--I want to hide the next 3 tds on some condition-->
            <td class="status2" colspan="2">&#160;</td>
            <td class="bold status2">status 2:</td>
            <td class="status2"><select>
                    <option value="null">select</option>
                    <option value="SV">V - 1</option>
                    <option value="SK">V - 2</option>
            </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="status3">
            <td width="20%" class="bold">Status 3:</td>
            <td><select>
                    <option value="null">select</option>
                    <option value="SV">V - 3</option>
                    <option value="SK">V - 4</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery selectors.

here's a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/udrohgf5/1/

I've used the following selector in order to hide the cells.

```
$('table tr:first td:lt(3)').hide();
```

which is basically - take the first 3 cells of the first row, and hide them.

`:first` - first occurance of that element.

`:lt(n)` - element index is **l**ower **t**han `n`